# GAE: Channel API: ApplicationError: 1

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

GAE seems to throw an ApplicationError: 1 on some code that has worked before. It could be a general GEA problem or some version upgrade issue as the code last was used a while ago. How would I debug that error?

```
ApplicationError: 1  (/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py:1552)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/e~(AppId)/dev.(VersionId)/worker.py", line 732, in post
    channel.send_message('status-' + userId, str(emailCount) + ":" + str(emailTotal))
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/channel/channel.py", line 242, in send_message
    raise _ToChannelError(e)
ApplicationError: ApplicationError: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The Channels API has been shutdown; the decprecation page is [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/deprecations/channel).

It states:

> The Channel API did not scale well enough for the workloads it was
>   intended for and so did not find wide adoption. Accordingly, support
>   for the Channel API will be shut down for brief periods of time for
>   maintenance beginning on July 13, 2017, as described in the shutdown
>   timetable. The service will be turned off permanently on **October 31,
>   2017**.

The recommended alternative is to use Firebase:

> See [Using Firebase for realtime events on App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/using-firebase-real-time-events-app-engine) for information on replacing Channel API functionality with the Firebase Realtime Database.