# Realtime bidirectional communication in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, client-server

I am working on a multi-user system that is already hosted in Google App Engine during development and I need to know a few things about Google Cloud that **I don't find in the docs:**

Is it possible to implement *Realtime bidirectional client server architecture* **WITHOUT FIREBASE?** since this project and scope is too big for firebase in my view, besides, firebase costs would shoot too high in the long run and lock me in when huge data is already involved in spite of insufficient queries. If possible, any hint would be appreciated.

**INFO:** Server is written in **nodejs** and **Mysql 2nd Generation** is the DB used. Main client is **Android**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of Firebase, since the [Channel API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400348/gae-channel-api-applicationerror-1) has been deprecated, your options are really only:

- run a full-time server (flexible environment, GCE) with a real-time framework like [socket.io](https://socket.io)
- use a real time service like [pubnub](https://pubnub.com) or [pusher](https://pusher.com)